# python excel to csv conversion generating wrong output

Tags: python, excel, csv

I wrote this code below where I am converting an `excel` sheet to `csv` file. It works fine if there are single line data in each `excel` cell but if the `excel` cell has multiple line data then it generates wrong output. Below is sample data from `excel`:

```
Domain ; State ; Industry; Simulation ; Simulation offers public quick access to  information and analysis – e.g., reports, news, data, and trends. 
Domain ; State ; Industry ; VT ; VR enables people to view simulation of virtual environement
Dynamic visualization increases analysis capabilities
Provides answers to questions such as:
- Where are the biggest opportunities for scaling?
- How should resources be aligned to increase performance?
- How much are people are spending per transaction or on a particular virtualization?
```

As you can see the first row of the `excel` sheet has single line data in each cell and so it comes correct but the second row had a multiple line data in it's last cell and when I run my code it treats each line in this cell as separate value and so each line comes in separate row in converted `csv`. Below is my code:

```
import xlrd
import csv


def Excel2CSV(ExcelFile, SheetName, CSVFile):

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFile)
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(SheetName)
    csvfile = open(CSVFile, 'w',newline = '',encoding='utf8')
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=';')

    for rownum in range(worksheet.nrows):

        wr.writerow(worksheet.row_values(rownum))

    csvfile.close()
```

How can I make sure multiple line data in a single cell remains together when converting `excel` sheet to `csv`(I don't care if the multiple line data from an excel cell becomes single line data in csv)?

Comment: I can not replicate your error, can you paste part of your excel?

Comment: It's already in the post above. `Domain ; State ; Industry; Simulation ; Simulation offers public quick access...` is one row with the last column having data in single line. `Domain ; State ; Industry ; VT ; VR enables people....` is second row with data in last column(everything after enables people is one column) but in multiple lines withine one column